# Jquery appendTo should target a specific container

Tags: jquery, append

- I have containers with same divs but different content.
- I want to move `$dispatch` and `$delivery` to a specific div on the same container

How can I appendTo the right content on the same div, without having repetition from other container divs?

Please have a look the demo, its showing that the Appended content is not targeted properly.

Demo:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/yLsx9nrz/

Js:

```
$this = $('.accordion-wrapper');
$dispatch = $this.find(".dispatch div");
$delivery = $this.find(".delivery div");

$dispatch.appendTo('.mobile-view .dispatch');
$delivery.appendTo('.mobile-view .delivery');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this for each container, one solution would be to use [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). Then, since [`.appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) also allows you to pass a jQuery object, you can then use `.appendTo($this.find('.mobile-view .delivery'));` to specify which div you want to append to:

```
var $wrappers = $('.accordion-wrapper');
$wrappers.each(function(index, el) {
    var $this = $(el);
    var $dispatch = $this.find(".dispatch div");
    var $delivery = $this.find(".delivery div");

    $dispatch.appendTo($this.find('.mobile-view .dispatch'));
    $delivery.appendTo($this.find('.mobile-view .delivery'));
});
```

Updated Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/yLsx9nrz/1/